# Testing Smaato native ads - Publisher ID and Adspace ID

Tags: publishing, native-ads, smaato

I am trying to test Smaato ads for an app. For both Publisher ID and Adspace ID, I enter '0' for testing. This works fine for all the ads except for **VAST Video** and **Native ads**, It requests different ID numbers.

For *VAST Video I found the solution*, but I do not know how to test Native Ads. I will be happy for any help on the subject.

P.S.

I rather to test an app that has ad spaces that refer me to real ads, so I can see the real ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing Video Ads enter for Publisher ID: 0 and for Adspace ID: 3090.

For testing Native Ads enter for Publisher ID: 0 and for Adspace ID:3075.

Comment: for native ad the Ad is not loading on Simulator with my Publisher Id and Adspace Id. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @GautamSareriya sorry, I can't be to useful I am pretty far from this subject these days. Did you try the generic Publisher ID 0, as mentioned in the answer? It could be that Smato also changed the Adspace ID.

Comment: Yes I used the the same that you have provided in the answer and working fine for test Ad. But when I'm replacing with my original Publisher id and Adspace id, it's not loading the Ad.